# How to re-insert selected nodes as "last siblings"

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a collection of SVG groups `g1`, `g2`, ..., `gn`, each having *m* paths as children.  The paths in each group have distinct classes `"C1"`, `"C2"`, ..., `"Cm"`.  Only these paths have these classes.  Therefore, a selection such as `d3.selectAll(".C1")` (or, alternatively, `$(".C1")`) will consist of exactly *n* paths, one from each of the groups `g1`,...,`gn`.

The paths in each group can overlap visually, but there is no overlap between paths in different groups.

Initially all the paths are colored black, and I would like to implement the ability to highlight (with a different color) all the paths belonging to a particular class.

An expression like

```
d3.selectAll("." + cx).attr("style", "stroke: #0f0")
```

or

```
$("." + cx).attr("style", "stroke: #0f0")
```

will set to green (#0f0) the color of all the paths having class `cx` (where `cx` holds one of the strings `"C1"`, ..., `"Cm"`), but unfortunately it often fails to produce the desired highlighting effect, namely, when the selected paths are visually obscured by the other paths.  (IOW, these not-highlighted paths get to be drawn "on top" of the highlighted ones, thereby obscuring the latter, at least partially.)

One solution would be to, before changing their color, first re-insert the selected paths into the DOM so that they are the *last* ones among their (by-design-unselected) siblings.

Of course, one could imagine writing some elaborate DOM-manipulation code to achieve this, but it occurs to me that this is precisely the type of code that `d3` and `jQuery` are meant to make unnecessary.

What would be the right incantation for doing this?  And also, would there be any reason to prefer one of `d3` or `jQuery` for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found one way to do this, at least with `jQuery`:

```
$("." + cx).each(function(){
                   var n = $(this);
                   var p = n.parent();
                   n.detach().appendTo(p);
                 }).attr("style", "stroke: #0f0");
```

(This *seems* to work, although I can't vouch for its correctness, or for its superiority over other methods, especially those using `d3` instead of `jQuery`.)

Answer (score 1):

[selection.sort(comparator)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-sort) will reorder the DOM.